# SQL Server 2008 R2 Most Efficient Full Text Search Field Type

Tags: sql-server, full-text-search

In SQL Server 2008 R2, what is the most efficient column type to store data enabling full text search?

I can currently see two options, `nvarchar` and `varbinary`.

Which one performs better and why?

**EDIT**

If, for example, at the moment all I need is text, but in the future it might change, will there be a performance hit if i use varbinary?

Answer (score 3):

`varbinary` is for binary data.

`nvarchar` is for character data.

Regardless of what the full text index is capable of indexing, use a data type suited to the domain.

Also, you will be able to see the contents of a `nvarchar` column in directly SSMS.

- [Best Practices for Choosing a Language When Creating a Full-Text Index](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/search/choose-a-language-when-creating-a-full-text-index?view=sql-server-ver16)
- [Best Practices for Integrated Full Text Search (iFTS) in SQL 2008](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/sqlcat/best-practices-for-integrated-full-text-search-ifts-in-sql-2008)

Performance issues are more likely to do with the frequency of maintenence of indexes, and hardware such as where your data is stored (as in a separate Filegroup), and memory usage, and indexing type (full population, incremental, manual, and auto change tracking population).

> Note that SQL Server 2008 full-text search is more aggressive in
> memory usage and may use more I/O; 64‑bit architectures are better
> than 32‑bit in doing crawl tasks in general.
>
> Sometimes crawl can be too aggressive in committing memory and this
> could cause sqlserver/system to have fewer resources than needed. It
> is highly recommended that you do the following:
>
> - Limit the memory used by the crawl (full population) by setting max server memory to an appropriate value to prevent the crawl task from
>   taking all available memory.
> - Increase the page file size if applicable.
>
> Indexing performance is generally superior to SQL Server 2005.
> However, in certain situations there may be some performance
> degradation as follows:
>
> - Crawl on large documents (~>8KB). In non 64‑bit platforms, this might be slower in some scenarios.
> - varchar type data. This is because SQL Server 2005 does a better job with the varchar type than with a text type, whereas in the new
>   full-text architecture **there is no difference in theory between varchar data and text data**.
> - Noninteger keys, especially GUID columns used as a full-text key
> - Too many unique keywords. It has been shown in random document crawl modes that performance can be slower than SQL Server 2005 (when
>   uniquekeycount > 80 million).
>
> Ref: [SQL Server 2008 Full-Text Search: Internals and Enhancements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008/cc721269%28v=sql.100%29)

Comment: if, for example, at the moment the domain is only text, but in the future it might change, will there be a performance hit if i use varbinary?